# What calls this method? Confused

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't understand when and what calls this function:

```
def current_user
 @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end
```

it's from: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code:current_user_working

When it kick in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [little higher up](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code%3asessions_helper_include) you'll see this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

This means that `current_user` is available in all your controllers and all your views. So any time you need to know who the current user is for access control, filtering data, assigning a creator to a new object, put their name in the upper right corner of the page, etc. you can ask `current_user`.